# Upgrading from Customer Portal

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal

My organisation has been using Customer Portal to allow their contacts/authenticated users access to static content as well as a custom object which is essentually mirrored to Opportunities.
When they create a new record in the object, parts of the data is then copied into a new Opportunity (with apex).

The solution works, however the visual customisations are too restricted despite being able to edit the CSS, header and footer. Theres also no way to edit the login page, allow certain sections of the site public access and etc.

I wanted to know what is the best solution to be able to get full control of these points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you migrating to a customer community from portal? If so - you can create a custom login and landing page, as well as create awesome visual sites/pages. There is a good migration document located at: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_portal_to_community_migration_cheatsheet.pdf

and a good DF video at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1QTjV-Md_I

Comment: Great info. The company I work for just made the jump from customer portal to communities and were able to change the entire look. It doesn't even look like SalesForce anymore. Except for the url... its /apex/class for custom logic. But normal users probably won't pick up on that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to migrate a communities to gain full control of your portal/site. You can build fully customizable VF pages on top of a customer portal.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for full customisation? In particular full page customisation and login pages

Comment: There is no special guide other than the visualforce developer guide. All you need really is to start replacing your standard pages with visualforce pages.

Comment: I dont belive you can replace the standard login page or manually code the menu component.

Comment: @Imran If you are using sites and have your site enabled for customer portal login, all you need to do is to create a new VF page that uses the login method from the Site class. This will log your users into the portal, since it will be your own VF page you will be able to customize every aspect of it. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm

Comment: So it will be a mixture of communities and sites? would it not be similar and more consistant to use one or the other? I think I've made up my mind, I've started to build a site.com version of the portal testing to see whether it will meet all my requirements